# Am I doing enough to ensure a secure login session?

Tags: php

I'm new to sessions and have only just read up on them. I've created a simple login form and wanted some advice about whether I've done this right.

I have a table in my database with only one entry (only one user can login) and the following check is made when the form is submitted:

```
function loginWithDetails($username,$password) {
    global $dbh;

    $stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE id = '1'");
    $stm->execute();
    $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $row['password']);

    if (!$check)
        return 0;
    else {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['username'];
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This function is placed inside my `functions.php` file which is included in `index.php` (where `session_start()` is called) and uses [Phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for hashing. Thereafter I check for `$_SESSION['userid']` to confirm that the user is logged. Everything is working fine but I want to be sure that the method is sufficient enough to check for login.

Comment: If you aren't comparing the $username submitted with $row['username'] then why even have a username?

Comment: Maybe an unset($_SESSION['userid']); before the return 0; would reduce confusion.

Comment: There is a piece of google code here that looks ok.  https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-secure-login-script-example/source/browse/branches/index.php

Comment: @cryptic in hindsight I probably should have left out the username field in the table. Other than that would you say the code is sufficient?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a database when you are just checking a single password. You should just use a .htpasswd

Comment: Judging from the `new PasswordHash`, this is built on top of Wordpress, right?  That probably explains the database access for such a simple thing.